# Troubles with CSS defined in CssResource

Tags: gwt

I am having some problem displaying the CSS using UiBinder and CssResource:

```
public interface Resources extends ClientBundle {

    @NotStrict
    @Source("style.css")
    Style style();

    @Source("logo.png")
    ImageResource logo();
}

public interface Style extends CssResource {
    @ClassName("orange")
    public String orange();
}
```

If I apply the CSS like this with UiBinder:

```
styleName="{res.style.orange}"
```

It doen't work, although the CSS "`.orange`" rule here is fully tested to be rendered properly.

I have defined the resouce in the UiBinder like this:

```
<ui:with field='res' type='com.mygwtapp.client.Resources'/>
```

And if I place this for example:

```
<g:Image resource='{res.logo}'/>
```

It works, the logo image is displayed but the CSS won't work. Is there any other procedure or method that I have missed that is causing the CSS not to be rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `ensureInjected()` on your `CssResources`.

UiBinder does it automatically for a `ui:style`, but not for `CssResources` you provide *via* an `ui:with`.